# How can I convert opus packets to mp3/wav

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, opus

I created a discord bot with discord.js v13, I get trouble with converting the opus packet to other file types, even the discord.js official examples haven't updated for discord.js v13, I got no idea to deal with it, here is part of my code

```
async function record(interaction, opts = {}) {
    //get voice connection, if there isn't one, create one
    let connection = getVoiceConnection(interaction.guildId);
    if (!connection) {
        if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) return false;
        connection = joinVoice(interaction.member.voice.channel, interaction)
    }
    const memberId = interaction.member.id;

    //create the stream
    const stream = connection.receiver.subscribe(memberId, {
        end: {
            behavior: EndBehaviorType.Manual
        }
    });
    //create the file stream
    const writableStream = fs.createWriteStream(`${opts.filename || interaction.guild.name}.${opts.format || 'opus'}`);
    console.log('Created the streams, started recording');
    //todo: set the stream into client and stop it in another function
    return setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Creating the decoder')
        let decoder = new prism.opus.Decoder();
        console.log('Created');

        stream.destroy();
        console.log('Stopped recording and saving the stream');
        stream
        .pipe(writableStream)
        stream.on('close', () => {
            console.log('Data Stream closed')
        });
        stream.on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(e)
        });
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Same problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `frameSize`, `channels` and `rate` for the `Decoder`:

```
const opusDecoder = new prism.opus.Decoder({
  frameSize: 960,
  channels: 2,
  rate: 48000,
})
```

Also not sure if it is intended, but you seem to destroy the `stream` just before you pipe it into writable stream.

Here is my example that gives stereo 48kHz signed 16-bit PCM stream:

```
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('samples/output.pcm')
const listenStream = connection.receiver.subscribe(userId)

const opusDecoder = new prism.opus.Decoder({
  frameSize: 960,
  channels: 2,
  rate: 48000,
})

listenStream.pipe(opusDecoder).pipe(writeStream)
```

You can then use [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/) to play the PCM file. Use File -> Import -> Raw Data...

[image: how to import in Audacity]